# How to fetch data from a website and show in metro app using c# and XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I want to show data/text from a website to my metro app.
Suppose structure of the website is like this:
website.html

```
<p id="name">
Peter
</p>
<p id="lastname">
Parker
</p>
```

Now I have 2 textblocks as "name" and "lastname".
How to make connection with www.sample.com/sample.html and show name and lastname?

Answer (score 0):

Not only is this a pretty involved process it's generally considered a bad approach at best and unethical at worst.

If you control this website then it's considered a bad approach because your site should be able to provide this data through the means of a web service using JSON or XML. HTML makes a poor medium for providing data.

If you don't control this website are you sure the owner of this information would approve of you scraping their website. If not then it's pretty unethical to try.